# open a CSV with 2 columns, and convert just one column into a list Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV like this:

```
https://www.website.com,"[""example0@email.com""]"
https://www.website2.com,"[""example1@email.com"",""example2@email.com""]"
```

and want it like this:

```
example0@email.com
example1@email.com
example2@email.com
```

I'd like convert this file into a single column list of just emails, ignoring the websites listing altogether. but also one website might return 10 emails so I'd like them all to go into the same single column.
How do I write this CSV into a new csv of just a single column of emails... (also as separate issue, is CSV the best way to do it, is there a substantially quicker way like tuple?) Ive been on excel 20 years so just getting my head around Python. and still think like a spreadsheet! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    emails = list()
    for row in csv_reader:
        for row in row[1:]:
            for email in row.split(","):
                emails.append(email.strip("[]").strip("\""))
with open('answer.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for email in emails:
        writer.writerow([email])
```

Comment: this worked in its own strange way and very fast (avoiding Pandas!). I just need to adjust a little as the results were like this:


""

example@email.com

example@email.com

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""

""



""

""

""

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into the python Pandas package. If you like excel, you'll probably like pandas.

Import the package

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read in your data (you'll be using the pd.read_csv(<insert path/file_name here>)

```
data = dict(col1 = ['https://www.website.com','https://www.website2.com'],\
           col2 = ['"[""example0@email.com""]"','"[""example1@email.com"",""example2@email.com""]"'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

From here you could go a number of ways, either just dealing with the column of interest (df[col2]) or exploding the whole table. First, need to get rid of the extra " and brackets, again using some of the functional attributes of string objects:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'"','')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r'[','')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace(r']','')
```

The turn the emails in to a list of strings rather than a long string. strings have the ability to split:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(',')
```

Now explode:

```
df = df.explode('col2')
```

And if you only really want the emails, just look at:

```
df['col2']
```

And to make it a csv file, you can use the df.to_csv file. The docs have a lot of good examples.

Comment: because this broader program is interacting with 100s of websites, combining this with python is too probably too slow, but this info is really useful to me as I've done some very basic pandas things. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv")
sites = df.iloc[0]
sites_list = []
for site in sites:
    site = site.split(sep=",")
    for s in site:
        sites_list.append(s)

result = [i.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "") for i in sites_list]
 
>> ['https://www.website2.com', 'example1@email.com', 'example2@email.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

using powerfull of generators:

```
import re

def read_emails(file):
     with open(file, 'r') as f:
         for item in f:
             yield from map(lambda x: f'{x}\n', re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', item))


def write_emails(file, items):
     with open(file, 'w') as f:
         f.writelines(items)


write_emails('result.txt', read_emails('test.csv'))
```

result:

```
cat result.txt 
example0@email.com
example1@email.com
example2@email.com
```

Comment: I think this works 99% of the time, but regex is difficult with emails. In fact I'm curious about your exact regex used, as its different to the https://emailregex.com/ definition. Also this is probably a bit slower than just throwing out a list, but thank you, I'll be using this code in a different way